# OAuthException Error When Posting Request to Instagram API

Tags: node.js, express, instagram-api

I am trying to get an access token using NodeJS/Express. I have provided all the requested parameters for the POST request but keep getting this error: `Code 400, error_type: 'OAuthException', error_message: 'You must provide a client_id'`. Any idea why this is happening? All the forums I've been to say it might be an Instagram issue. Am I not using the request module correctly in my application?

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(4000,function(){
   console.log("Listening to app on localhost 4000"); 
})

var clientId =  "7be53c459291486ead4916048ac434ad";
var redirect_uri = "http://localhost:4000/feed";
var instaLink = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id="+clientId+"&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+"&response_type=code";
var client_secret = "88ad262f9e57481bbf1ea7312d179a50";

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    console.log("Visited Index");
    res.redirect(instaLink);
})

app.get('/feed',function(req,res) {
    var code = req.query.code;

    var url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token";
    var options = {
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        body: {
            client_id : clientId,
            client_secret : client_secret,
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
            code: code
        },
        json: true
    }

    request(options, function(err,res,body){
        console.log(body);
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1):

try replace **body** property with **form** in here

```
var options = {
    url: url,
    method: 'POST',
    form: {
        client_id : clientId,
        client_secret : client_secret,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        code: code
    }
};
request(options, function(err,res,body){
    console.log(body);
})
```

Comment: This worked! Where can I find simple documentation that shows what properties go into the options object? I read that body should be used not form.

Comment: form property is application/x-www-form-urlencoded request. You can read document in here https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-url-encoded-forms